# How add image button and navigate it by angular material

Tags: angular-material-7

I want to make a button with including an (image on button) by angular material. as well as i want to link this button for a component what is relative to the button.
That's mean when i click the image as above mentioned, component should be visible on my project. then how i do this.

Comment: Not clear to me

Comment: Can you please explain bit more?